# Should changing a few characters in a private key meaningfully change it?

Tags: encryption, key, jwt, rsa

so we have a private key used to sign requests which are later decrypted using the public key.  I was messing around with it and replaced a few characters in it, say changing 'wnoy' to 'xxyy'

I suspected this would essentially change the key and the decryption fail as a result but this wasn't the case.  Are the changes simply too small to result in a meaningful change to the key?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any change to the modulus, exponent or CRT parameters that are used during calculation will result in failure of the algorithm to produce a correct signature or in failure during decryption (most likely producing a padding error).

However, because an RSA private key is not just a single number it is commonly saved in a PKCS#1 defined ASN.1 / DER encoded structure. Now it depends on what you change of this structure if the private key is damaged enough or not. The encoding of this structure (if it is a PEM private key) may also play a role.

Most likely you have changed the public or private exponent while the RSA CRT parameters are being used in the calculation (either the private exponent or CRT parameters are used for the calculations). In that case the calculation will proceed as normal. You would have about 256 bytes that can be changed without causing a problem for a 2048 bit key.

The slower "plain" RSA calculation uses the private exponent, which means that any change to the CRT parameters will go unnoticed (unless the structure doesn't parse anymore). For a 2048 bit key you would very likely have over 5 x 128 bytes that can be changed without causing a problem!

---

From PKCS#1:

```
RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    version           Version,
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
    privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
    prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
    prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
    exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
    exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
    coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
    otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
}
```

here the CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem) parameters are the prime1, prime2, exponent1, exponent2 and finally coefficient parameters.

Comment: thank you for taking the time Maarten, it's much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. If you want to test if a change does break decryption then change, say, the 20th byte / character of the private key (presuming it does indeed use the above structure). You are very likely to alter the modulus that way. The modulus *must* be used and it is unique for each RSA key pair.